# Android Typeface Font Default / Fallback

Tags: android, fonts

I draw (canvas) a text using a custom typeface (precisely: I use a custom font). However, this font doesn't support many characters and thus some (unsupported) characters are looking differently. Now I am asking myself the following questions:

- How does an unsupported character look like - does the look depend on a system setting / is the look the same on all devices?
- What (default) font is used for unsupported characters? (do the unsupported letters have the same dimensions as the supported ones in the end?)

Comment: if you're using canvas, you're assuming total control over your content. If you are using characters that are not support, you already know when that is, and should handle that. Alternatively, if you're just writing text, don't write text using canvas. You already have HTML available for that, with font stack support and feature selections using CSS3. It's worth taking advantage of that.

Comment: Hello Mike, thank you for your input. However, we are not talking about web development but Android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I digged through the Android code and would like to post my findings:

A **Typeface.class** instance is created using the static create-methods of the **Typeface.class** (createFromAsset/createFromFile/create/etc.). The instance then holds a list of fonts (unmodifiable `List<Font>`). The first element of this list is the main font (specified) and the other elements (index: 1 - (size-1)) are default fonts which are retrieved from the **FontLoader.class** (`getFallBackFonts()`)

Among others, the **Paint.class** / **Canvas.class** (`drawText()`) use a **Typeface.class** instance to draw the texts (to measure characters / to draw / etc.). They try to use the main font (`Typeface.mFonts[0]`) when possible. If a character cannot be found in the main font then they try to use a fallback font (`Typeface.mFonts[1]`-`Typeface.mFonts[size-1]`) to measure and draw the character.

***Conclusion***

You can use a Typeface.class instance if you want to use a custom font. If your custom font doesn't support certain characters that you want to draw (/that you use in your text) then the system tries to make use of fallback-fonts. These fallback fonts are loaded from the system by the FontLoader.class (from a system-xml).